# Flutter doctor throwing error 'curl: (6) Could not resolve host: storage.googleapis.com'

Tags: flutter, curl

I have installed flutter on my `Ubuntu-16.04 LTS` machine with the below command:

`sudo snap install flutter --classic`

Then I ran the command: `flutter doctor`

I get the below errors :

```
(base) mickey@KRY:~$ flutter doctor
Initializing Flutter
Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_1.22.2-stable.tar.xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 51  510M   51  263M    0     0   213k      0  0:40:47  0:21:02  0:19:45     0
curl: (56) **OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 113**
xz: (stdin): Unexpected end of input
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Flutter initialized
Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project.
       The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
       to install Flutter, see the instructions at:
       https://flutter.dev/get-started
Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project.
       The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
       to install Flutter, see the instructions at:
       https://flutter.dev/get-started


(base) mickey@KRY:~$ flutter doctor
Initializing Flutter
Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_1.22.2-stable.tar.xz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0**curl: (6) Could not resolve host: storage.googleapis.com**
xz: (stdin): Unexpected end of input
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Flutter initialized
Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project.
       The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
       to install Flutter, see the instructions at:
       https://flutter.dev/get-started
Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project.
       The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
       to install Flutter, see the instructions at:
       https://flutter.dev/get-started
(base) mickey@KRY:~$
```

I'm new to flutter, just started with it. Where am I going wrong?
Could someone assist me in resolving this issue?

Thank You,
Kishor.

Answer (score 0):

The flutter script checks whether there is a `.git` directory in the working directory. If this directory is not present better to re-clone.

`git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`

Then try to open `flutter_console.bat` and run any flutter command to check whether it is working or not.

Comment: thanks for the answer to the above query. I tried to run the command again 'flutter doctor'. The issue was resolved. I guess the issue was due to Network Speed. I rerun the command and it worked. Thank you very much for the quick answer.

Comment: One more thing is that even if I install using "sudo snap install flutter --classic" should I check for .git directory in my working directory?

Comment: Yes. If my answer resolved your question you can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark